# How to download current flow from mitmweb?

Tags: mitmproxy

In `mitmweb`, the *Download* button seems to do the same job as *Download the content of the flow* button in the *Response* tab, which, despite its misleading name, saves only response body and is incompatible with the server-side replay feature. I did not find a way to save the entire flow as in mitmproxy, so I had to switch to the command-line tool in order to produce the file in compatible format. Is it possible to do the same from the web UI (`mitmweb`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on "mitmproxy" at the top left and then "Save", you will get a dump file containing all flows.

Comment: Indeed! I don't know how I missed that.